# how to call the database created in Sqlite browser fromm my android emulator

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to access sqlitedatabase from my emulator , the database is created in sqlitebrowser want to call in my android emulator simultaneously insert ,update ,select query is fire

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you can't, unless I don't understand sqlite access in its full myriad forms.  You'd need some type of network connection.  I don't think you can mount the emulator drive or anything like that.

You could edit, then copy the whole db back and forth with adb commands.  Not simultaneous, but will get the job done.

I think you can use the command line sqlite tool through adb shell, and access the db that's on the emulator drive directly.

Comment: Thank you Kevin for your valuable suggestion